# Retrieving the last non-empty value and display it for each day

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I am new to `SSAS` and more so with `MDX` and I need your help with the following scenario please.

In my cube, there is a measure called WIP Hours (Work In Progress Hours).
This measure is from a measure group called WIP, which is based on a fact table, namely facWIP.

facWIP table gets its data from a source table.
Each time a user enters a WIP entry to the front-end system, that entry is stored in this table.
However, users don't always put an entry everyday.

For example, there is an entry for `16 Aug 2013 and the WIP value = 47`.
The next entry is on `26 Aug 2013 of WIP = 42`
There are no entries for 17 Aug - 25 Aug 2013 in the source table, hence the same in the fact table.

This is reflected in the cube that I build.
The requirement is that if there are no entries for a particular date, then need to use / display the last number available.
So in this case, in the cube there should be entries for 17 - 25 August with WIP = 47, etc.

I have no idea how to do this, if it is possible at all.
I tried using the following MDX

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[WIP Hours_2]
AS
(TAIL(NONEMPTY(DESCENDANTS([Calendar].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER,[Calendar].[Calendar].[Calendar Date]), [Measures].[WIP Hours]),1).ITEM(0), [Measures].[WIP Hours]),
//NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Measures].[WIP Hours] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'WIP' ;
```

but it doesn't do what I want.

---

UPDATE 8 Sept 2013:

I am also trying another alternative approach, that is to Cross Join the table with the calendar table so that every task WIP combination has entries for each day.
For the entries which actually does not have actual WIP value, it will be WIP = NULL.
The downside of this approach is that the fact table becomes much bigger and longer ETL process, from 1.5M to ~17M records!

I am thinking by doing it this way, somehow in the cube calculated measure using MDX, I can say something like:
"If the WIP for current date is NULL, then get/use the last non-NULL WIP value"
How can I write this logic in MDX, if it makes sense at all?

Also, at the moment, in the cube, the date entries which actually have WIP = NULL, their WIP is showing = 0..

Any assistance are very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try a recursive approach:

```
// intermediate measure, makes the code more readable:
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Calendar].[Calendar].[last day in period] AS
       Tail(Descendants([Calendar].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER,
                        [Calendar].[Calendar].[Calendar Date]
            )
       ).Item(0).Item(0),
VISIBLE = 0;

// final measure, defined using recursion:
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[WIP Hours_2]
AS
IIf(IsEmpty( ( [Calendar].[Calendar].[last day in period], [Measures].[WIP Hours] )),
    ( [Calendar].[Calendar].[last day in period].PrevMember, [Measures].[WIP Hours_2] ),
    ( [Calendar].[Calendar].[last day in period], [Measures].[WIP Hours] )
),
VISIBLE = 1 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'WIP' ;
```

The `true` case of the `IIf` is the recursion, the second case the termination of the recursion. SSAS should be able to end the recursion itself as soon it reaches the start of the `Calendar` hierarchy, avoiding an infinite recursion.

If the above does not give you the correct answer, maybe using `<> 0` instead of `IsEmpty` will get better results.

Comment: thanks for your response.
i just tried your solution but it doesnt work.. WIP_2 values are all #VALUE!. It complains that

"The function expects string or numeric expression for the argument. A tuple set expression was used"

I think it is referring to the IIF statement's argument. I am not sure how to fix it? Help please.. thanks again

Comment: please also see my question above as I just updated it with alternative approach, which you may be able to help me as well.. Thank you

Comment: I would assume that the [last day in period] calculation was wrong, I updated my answer.